# rspec Error: expecting <"index"> but rendering with <"">

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have looked at all the other posts regarding this error, but nothing has worked:

carrier_spec.rb

```
require 'rspec'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'rails_helper'
require 'helpers'


RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include Helpers

end


RSpec.describe CarriersController, :type => :controller do


  describe "#index" do
    render_views
    it 'should get index' do
      CarriersController.prepend_view_path(root_path)
      login_id = login_admin
      expect(response).to be_successful


      get :index, :format => "html"
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
      # var = FactoryGirl.create(:carrier)
      # expect(var.valid?).to eql(true)
    end
  end

end
```

helpers.rb

```
module Helpers
  def login(user)
    request.session[:user] = user.id
  end

  def login_admin
    admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)

    expect(admin.valid?).to eql(true)
    expect(admin.admin?).to eql(true)
    expect(admin.device_admin?).to eql(true)

    login(admin)
  end
end
```

carriers_controller.rb

```
  # GET /carriers
  # GET /carriers.json
def index
    @carriers = Carrier.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @carriers }
    end

  end
```

I'm not sure why this is happening... 
I know the index page loads to /carriers, not /carriers/index.html, but does that make a difference?

Comment: Try to insert `save_and_open_page` before `expect` it's very useful in such cases. You need gems capybara and launchy to do this

Comment: Start by doing some debugging - if nothing is being rendered then perhaps it's a redirect - check test.log to find out where to

Comment: I think it is a redirect, but the errors remain the same.